# rails migration script VS console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, data-migration

so i am trying to migrate some data in a migration script, but the data does not seem to be saving.  however, if i copy the code and run it directly in the console, it does save. can anyone help me figure out why?

this is the code from my migration script. i am moving my avatar data from its own table into my profiles table.

```
  def self.up
    add_column :users,    :featured,            :boolean, :default => false
    add_column :profiles, :avatar_file_name,    :string
    add_column :profiles, :avatar_content_type, :string
    add_column :profiles, :avatar_file_size,    :integer
    add_column :profiles, :avatar_updated_at,   :datetime

    Avatar.all.each do |a|
      user = User.find(a.user_id)
      user.profile.avatar_file_name = a.avatar_file_name
      user.profile.avatar_content_type = a.avatar_content_type
      user.profile.avatar_file_size = a.avatar_file_size
      user.profile.avatar_updated_at = a.updated_at
      if a.featured == true
        user.featured = true
      end
      user.save
    end

    # drop_table :avatars
  end
```

Comment: Instead of `if a.feature == true`, you can use `if a.feature?`. Rails automatically adds ? to the end of boolean attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's because you're changing the columns and trying to use them in the same migration, but the model doesn't know about the fields.

Try adding these lines above Avatar.all.each...

```
User.reset_column_information
Profile.reset_column_information
```

More about this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-reset_column_information

Comment: that was exactly it!  thanks!  the only problem now is that pesky featured column.  sqlite stores it as `t` & `f` and i cant seem to figure out how to carry that value over.  i have tried all sorts of combinations of `== true`, `== 't'`, checking `if featured?`.  im not sure what is happening under the hood, but just setting it like in my example doesnt work. they always return false.

Comment: @brewster: try `user.save!` in case you are missing an exception. It's generally a good thing to raise exceptions in migrations. You might also look in `log/development.log` to see the SQL that is executed.

Comment: @brewster - As zetetic stated, try using `save!`. It's likely that a user is invalid and this will show you why during the migration.

Comment: no such luck.   when i run it from the console it works fine.  i even see in my log `UPDATE "users" SET "featured" = 't', "updated_at" = '2010-12-16 21:36:40.630128' WHERE ("users"."type" = 'Client') AND ("users"."id" = 3)` but when i call that value its still false.  maybe the migration sets the defaults to false after the up method completes?

Comment: even STRANGER.... is if my migration script fails... and i re-run it, then it DOES work. im so confused ha